# Symfony 4 routing from pages

Tags: symfony, routes

In Symfony 4 I'm building a simple cms (based on AdminLTE) where a user could create pages, a page has te following properties:

## Page

1. id
2. title
3. slug
4. content
5. metaDescription
6. metaKeywords

When a page is created i want to use to page in the frontend and this is where i get stuck.

I really don't know where to start and how.

1. How could a page be coupled to some kind of menu for using it in the
   frontend.

   1a. In the feature there would be news items, agenda items and those have routes as wel.
2. I want to store the routes in the db, but how.

   2a. Is it best to create an Route entity that contains data for routing?

Hope you could help me out with these and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you install and run the [Symfony demo application](https://github.com/symfony/demo). You can then explore the code and see how things work in a very practical case.

Amongst other things, you'll notice that they don't use routing entities and store only minimal routing information in the database (such as page slugs). As for menus, it'll demonstrate how to build a very simple top navigation and how to hook it up with static and dynamic routes.

Good luck!